# How do you write specific bytes to a file?

Tags: files, software-rec, ascii

Given a file `myfile` with the following contents:

```
$ cat myfile
foos
```

A hexdump of the file gives us the contents:

```
$ hexdump myfile
6f66 736f 000a
```

Currently, I can create the file by specifying the contents in ascii like this:

```
$ echo foos > myfile
```

Is it possible to create the file by giving it the exact bytes in hexadecimal rather than ascii?

```
$ # How can I make this work?
$ echo --fake-hex-option "6f66 736f 000a" > myfile
$ cat myfile
foos
```

Update: For clarity's sake, I worded the question to ask how to write a small number of bytes to a file. In reality, I need a way to pipe a large amount of hexadecimal numbers directly into a file rather than just 3 bytes:

```
$ cat hexfile
6f66 736f 6f66 736f ...
$ some_utility hexfile > myfile
$ cat myfile
foosfoosfoosfoos...
```

Comment: I think you might like the -C flag for hexdump. `hexdump -C` displays a byte by byte output instead of 16 bit words obfuscated up by endianess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the `hexundump` script from my personal collection:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$^W = 1;
$c = undef;
while (<>) {
    tr/0-9A-Fa-f//cd;
    if (defined $c) { warn "Consuming $c"; $_ = $c . $_; $c = undef; }
    if (length($_) & 1) { s/(.)$//; $c = $1; }
    print pack "H*", $_;
}
if (!eof) { die "$!"; }
if (defined $c) { warn "Odd number of hexadecimal digits"; }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `echo -e`:

```
echo -e "\x66\x6f\x6f"
```

Do note that `hexdump -C` is what you want to dump the contents of the file in byte order instead of being interpreted as 4-byte words in network byte order.

Comment: Although this does answer my question, it doesn't help in my situation. I have a very large input of hexadecimal numbers that I would like to pipe into a file. I will update the question with this.

Answer (score 3):

Simulate a byte train:

```
echo 41 42 43 44 |
```

Change spaces into newlines so the while/read can easily parse them on by one

```
tr ' ' '\n' |
```

Parse byte by byte

```
while read hex; do
```

Convert hex to ascii:

```
  printf \\x$hex
```

until end of input

```
done
```

If the files to parse are seriously big, you probably don't want to use bash because it is slow. PERL for example would be a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

The *some_utility* you're finding is [`dd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29) ([manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html)). You can copy any valid bytes from any valid position of a file to another file by specify `bs`(block size), `count`, and `skip` options.

**Example**

Copy the first 1024 bytes of a file to another file.

```
$ dd if=liveusb-creator-3.11.7-setup.exe of=test.ex_ bs=1 count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1024 bytes (1.0 kB) copied, 0.03922 s, 26.1 kB/s
```

Answer (score 2):

To write arbitrary hex data to binary file:

```
echo -n 666f6f | xxd -r -p - file.bin
```

For hex (input) data stored in some file to be written to binary file:

```
xxd -r -p file.hex file.bin
```

To read binary data:
`hd file.bin` or `xxd file.bin`

To read data only (without offsets):

```
xxd -p file.bin
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can use `dc` to `P`rint the *`(UCHAR_MAX+1)`* value of a byte:

```sh
printf %dP 104 101 121 32 116 104 101 114 101 10 |dc
```

...which prints...

```sh
hey there
```

The default `i`nput radix is 10 - decimal - but you can set it with `$val i` where `$val` is any number between 2 and 16 *(note that if the current input radix is not 10 you'll have to use the current base's value for 10 to get it back - else you can always do `Ai`)*.

Here is a more complicated example:

```sh
LC_ALL=C man man 2>/dev/null | 
od -v -An -t x1 |
tr -s '[:space:]' P | {
    echo 16i0
    tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
} | dc | head
```

...which translates `man man`'s output into hexadecimal and back again in-stream and prints:

```
MAN(1)              Manual pager utils              MAN(1)



NAME
       man - an interface to the on-line reference manuals

SYNOPSIS
       man [-C file] [-d] [-D] [--warnings[=warnings]] [-R
       encoding] [-L locale] [-m system[,...]]  [-M  path]
```

Just ensure that all of your alphabetic `[:hexdigit:]`s are uppercase and sandwich a `P` between every pair then pipe it at `dc`.

Comment: That's a pretty impressive 3-liner. I'd be interested if you cared to elaborate on that regex!

Comment: @CoryKlein - the regex isn't really what matters - `sed` just inserts a `P` after every two not-space chars and appends the string `[]p` to every line. It is `dc` that is interesting. First `echo` sets its `i`nput radix to 16 *(so it will interpret the hex char pairs as numbers)* then for every byte it reads in it `P`rints its *(UCHAR_MAX+1)* value to stdout and pops it off the stack. Try `echo 8i141P12PAi97P10P16i61P0AP |dc` and see what you get.

Comment: With that, I get `a\na\na`, is that supposed to be what I see?

Comment: @CoryKlein - yeah. It sets the input radix to octal then prints the ascii char for the octal bytes 141 and 12 - then sets it to `A` *(10 - decimal)* and prints the ascii chars for 97 and 10, then sets it to hex and prints the ascii chars for 61 and 0A. All of those char pairs are `a\n`.