# echo bytes to a file

Tags: shell, quoting, character-encoding, echo

I'm trying to connect my rasberry Pi to some display using the i2c bus.
To get started I wanted to manually write stuff, bytes in particular to a file.
[How do you write specific bytes to a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55767/how-do-you-write-specific-bytes-to-a-file)
I already read that one and I figured my problem should be solved by something like this

```
echo -n -e \x66\x6f\x6f > byteFileForNow
```

However, when I open up that file with nano, instead of **foo** I see:

> x66x6fx6f

So the backslashes were escaped, but not the bytes themselves. I also tried the same only without the **-e** this time, so I would've exepected to see **\x66\x6f\x6f**, but got the same as before.

So echo is escaping backslashes, backslashes alone and backslashes regardless of if it is supposed to.
Any idea how to fix this?
According to the man-page that should've done what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You have to take your codes into quotes:

```
echo -n -e '\x66\x6f\x6f' > byteFileForNow
```

cause otherwise shell replaces `\x` to `x` before it goes to `echo -e`.

ps. double escape will also work:

```
echo -n -e \\x66\\x6f\\x6f > byteFileForNow
```

Comment: I got it to work with quotes, double quotes though.  
I kinda new it was something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Just be carefull as echo is (usually) a builtin shell command. `bash` handle `\xHH` properly, but not all shells do.

Answer (score 12):

#### Shell

In shell you can use `printf`:

```
printf "%b" '\x66\x6f\x6f' > file.bin
```

<sup>Note: `%b` - Print the associated argument while interpreting backslash escapes.</sup>

#### Perl

With perl, it is even simpler:

```
perl -e 'print pack("ccc",(0x66,0x6f,0x6f))' > file.bin
```

#### Python

If you've Python installed, try the following one-liner:

> `python -c $'from struct import pack\nwith open("file.bin", "wb") as f: f.write(pack("<bbb", *bytearray([0x66, 0x6f, 0x6f])))'`

---

Testing:

```
$ hexdump file.bin 
0000000 66 6f 6f
```

Comment: Or just `perl -e 'print pack "c*", 0x66, 0x6f, 0x6f'` or `perl -e 'print pack "H*", "666f6f"'`

Comment: Note that `printf %b '\x66'` is not portable. `printf '\x66'` is slightly more portable (works with `ksh93`, still not with `dash` nor `yash`). `printf '\146\157\157'` or `printf %b '\0146\0157\0157'` would be portable/standard.

Answer (score 2):

This might not answering directly the question, but you can also use `vi` in hex mode:

Open your file and type:
*ESC* `:%!xxd` to switch into hex mode.

You will be able to edit the hex part (the text part will not be updated as you change the hex part).

When your are done hit escape again and type:
*ESC* `:%!xxd -r` to write back the changes you did in hex mode (don't forget to save afterward).

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of information in the online manual for each command; it is always worth having a look at that before giving up and posting a question.

`man echo` explains which escape sequences are allowed. Here's an extract.

> ```
>    If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognized:
>
>    \0NNN  the character whose ASCII code is NNN (octal)
>
>    \\     backslash
>
>    \a     alert (BEL)
>
>    \b     backspace
>
>    \c     produce no further output
>
>    \f     form feed
>
>    \n     new line
>
>    \r     carriage return
>
>    \t     horizontal tab
>
>    \v     vertical tab
> ```

So \x86 is just incorrect. it must be octal and put your string in double quotes, otherwise it will be interpreted by the shell.

Example:

```
$ echo -e -n "\033\07\017" >tf
$ od -c tf
0000000 033  \a 017
0000003
```

Edit 1

As Ouki reminded me, echo is also a shell builtin, so the information is in the manual page for bash, `man bash`; here's the relevant section. But **use quotes** `"` around your string to stop the shell interpreting the back slashes.

> ```
>    echo [-neE] [arg ...]
>           Output  the  args, separated by spaces, followed by a newline.  The return status is always
>           0.  If -n is specified, the trailing newline is suppressed.  If the  -e  option  is  given,
>           interpretation  of  the  following  backslash-escaped characters is enabled.  The -E option
>           disables the interpretation of these escape characters, even  on  systems  where  they  are
>           interpreted  by  default.   The  xpg_echo shell option may be used to dynamically determine
>           whether or not echo expands these escape characters by default.  echo does not interpret --
>           to mean the end of options.  echo interprets the following escape sequences:
>           \a     alert (bell)
>           \b     backspace
>           \c     suppress further output
>           \e     an escape character
>           \f     form feed
>           \n     new line
>           \r     carriage return
>           \t     horizontal tab
>           \v     vertical tab
>           \\     backslash
>           \0nnn  the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (zero to three octal dig‐
>                  its)
>           \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex dig‐
>                  its)
> ```

Comment: The thing is `echo` is usually a builtin command. So this is up to the shell you are using. The linux default being `bash`; `\xHH` is properly displaying a character through its hexadecimal value.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, my bad. See my edit 1 update.